# Wizard with jQuery accordion, previous / next buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a wizard inside a accordion. Look at my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NDncE/2/

What am I doing wrong, I want the previous and next button on each accordion element.

Answer (score 5):

The proper solution using the latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmardeni/NDncE/49/

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">1. Profilbilde</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
           test
        </p>
        <button class='next'>
            Next
        </button>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">2. Organisasjon</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            test
        </p>
        <button class='previous'>
            Previous
        </button>
        <button class='next'>
            Next
        </button>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">3. Tjenestested</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            test
        </p>
        <button class='previous'>
            Previous
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accordion').accordion();
    $('#accordion button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = ($(this).is('.next') ? 1 : -1);
        $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', (
             $('#accordion').accordion('option','active') + delta  ));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hiya 2 solutions for you:

**>>>> Solution 1 <<<<**

Accordion() solution:

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/NDncE/9/

**Please NOTE With** previous and next button: http://jsfiddle.net/NDncE/12/

Missing script include:

**Code:**

```
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**>>>> Solution 2 <<<<**

here you go got a another working version for you: http://jsfiddle.net/NDncE/6/

Useful link please give a read: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion (Accordion Api & use)

**Jquery Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accordion h3').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
​
```

**HTML:** (No Changes)

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">1. Profilbilde</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
           test
        </p>
        <button>
            Last opp bildet
        </button>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">2. Organisasjon</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            test
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">3. Tjenestested</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            test
        </p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

This will help, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Small variation on the answer by @roberto-mardeni, programmatically clicking the next header rather than overriding the 'active' value:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyxba7pz/

**JS:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accordion').accordion();
    $('#accordion .next, #accordion .previous').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( $(this).hasClass('next') ) {
            $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').next('.ui-accordion-header').click();    
        } else if ( $(this).hasClass('previous') ) {
            $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').prevUntil('.ui-accordion-header:first').prev().click();    
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">1. Profilbilde</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
           test
        </p>
        <button class='next'>Next</button>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">2. Organisasjon</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            test
        </p>
        <button class='previous'>Previous</button>
        <button class='next'>Next</button>
    </div>
    <h3>
        <a href="#">3. Tjenestested</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            test
        </p>
        <button class='previous'>Previous</button>
    </div>
</div>
```