# How can I cycle through an accordions content using external buttons/controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

So I have a simple accordion here - https://jsfiddle.net/fLLbkxcf/ - which is using slideToggle to show and hide an accordions content.

```
$(".accordion_trigger").click(function () {
  $(this).next(".accordion_holder").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".accordion_holder:visible").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("current");
  $(this).siblings(".accordion_trigger").removeClass("current");
});
```

However I have some buttons below the accordion (next, previous) that I want to be able to cycle through the different states of the accordion.

Does anyone have any clues on how I should tackle this or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Button should like access tab keys. Then it can work.

Comment: Take a lock here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837175/wizard-with-jquery-accordion-previous-next-buttons

Comment: Simply use `.next()`/`.prev()` to get the next/previous sibling of the element with the class `current`. If that doesn’t return an element, then you know that you need to take the first/last element instead.

Comment: Hey @CBroe That sounds exactly what I want to do. That makes sense to me but I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to js. Could you show me in a fiddle how to execute it? Thanks again!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1a64Lyk6/2/?

Comment: @ArunPJohny That is perfect! Is there a way I can make your comment the answer? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a click handler, where you find the current element and then navigate based to whether to show prev/next element

```js
$(".accordion_trigger").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".accordion_holder").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".accordion_holder:visible").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("current");
  $(this).siblings(".accordion_trigger").removeClass("current");
});
$('.acc-ext-trigger').click(function() {
  var $curr = $(".accordion_trigger.current"),
    dir = $(this).data('dir');
  var $next = $curr[dir == -1 ? 'prevAll' : 'nextAll']('.accordion_trigger');
  $next = $next.length ? $next : $('.accordion_trigger')[dir == -1 ? 'last' : 'first']();
  $next.triggerHandler('click');
});
```

```css
.accordion_holder {
  display: none;
  background: #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.accordion_trigger {
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.accordion_trigger p,
.accordion_holder p {
  margin: 0;
}
/* Clearfix */

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Accordion 1 -->
<div class="accordion_trigger">
  <p class="leadin">Accordion Title 1</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion_holder">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Accordion 2 -->
<div class="accordion_trigger">
  <p class="leadin">Accordion Title 2</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion_holder">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Accordion 3 -->
<div class="accordion_trigger">
  <p class="leadin">Accordion Title 2</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion_holder">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Accordion controls -->
<a href="#" class="acc-ext-trigger" data-dir="1">Next</a>
<a href="#" class="acc-ext-trigger" data-dir="-1">Previous</a>
```

Comment: Hey @ArunPJohny. Thanks so much for the answer! I'm wondering if you can help me with one extra task? As well as the previous/next buttons I'm wanting to show an image for the corresponding accordion that is open. Do you know how I can show/hide this image/div holder? https://jsfiddle.net/1a64Lyk6/6/

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly! I think I did a bad job explaining what I was after. Sorry! So basically, each accordion holder is going to have content (which is currently does) and as well as that content it's going to have an image associated with it. So when an accordion element is selected I want to show the content and a corresponding image - ie - When 'Accordion title 1' is selected it will show the content within the 'Accordion title 1' and an image ('accordion image 1') which will be located next to the accordion. I hope that makes sense. Let me know if it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: I seriously can't thank you enough! Exactly what I'm after. Thanks so much!